# Cassandra shutdown caused by: java.io.SyncFailedException: sync failed

Tags: java, cassandra

I am using Cassnadra 2.1.13 single node cluster and database was running all good without any issues.

Then there was this following exception because of which Cassandra service was brought down.

In a single node cluster what could be the reason for these exceptions specially **sync failed**, any hints or pointers to get to the root cause of this issue?

> INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:22] Memtable.java:347 - Writing
>   Memtable-compaction_history@1884003282(0.521KiB serialized bytes, 19
>   ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit) INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:22]
>   Memtable.java:382 - Completed flushing
>   /myspace/db/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/system-compaction_history-tmp-ka-8-Data.db
>   (0.000KiB) for commitlog position
>   ReplayPosition(segmentId=1540762960100, position=2642365) ERROR
>   [MemtableFlushWriter:21] CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in
>   thread Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:21,5,main]
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.io.SyncFailedException:
>   sync failed
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.syncDataOnlyInternal(SequentialWriter.java:254)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.syncInternal(SequentialWriter.java:263)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.close(SequentialWriter.java:451)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.close(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:264)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.close(SSTableWriter.java:503)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.finish(SSTableWriter.java:455)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:447)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:442)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:389)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:335)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>   ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1120)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_192]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_192]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_192] Caused by: java.io.SyncFailedException: sync failed
>           at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.syncDataOnlyInternal(SequentialWriter.java:250)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           ... 15 common frames omitted
>
> **ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:21] StorageService.java:453 - Stopping
>   gossiper WARN  [MemtableFlushWriter:21] StorageService.java:359 -
>   Stopping gossip by operator request INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:21]
>   Gossiper.java:1455 - Announcing shutdown**

After restarting the Cassandra service there are no issues and working as expected.

Comment: Usually that could be a problem with disk where commit logs reside. What value of `commitlog_sync` parameter do you have?

Comment: The default ones:
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is either:

- disk issue - check the `/var/log/messages` and SMART status of the disk
- disk was full
- file was removed (although that's very improbable, but could happen if you have antivirus on the system)

Comment: Around same time of database crash can see this error "localhost logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]" in /var/log/messages, further then looked into logrotate.conf and "var_log_t" context. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39006

Disk full was not the case and regarding antivirus it is not running either.
Also is it pure timing issue here ?

Comment: yes, it could be a some kind of timing issues, but I think that it makes sense to monitor disks for errors...

Comment: look into `dmesg` as well

Comment: was not able to get anything with `dmesg`. Haven't faced issue later, what should be the conclusion here?

Comment: Thanks Alex for all the pointers here. Is there anything more that needs to be checked with 1) `commitlog_sync`, it is default on my system. 2) `/var/log/messages` error. If not then will keep monitoring for any such issues next.

Comment: One more thing, from the stack trace can see the service has completed flushing of `myspace/db/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/system-compaction_history-tmp-ka-8-Data.db` and then `sync failed` exception is seen, so is it disk issue or something internal with flush and sync?

Comment: I think I have seen some related CASSANDRA JIRA, but I think that it was fixed in your version... If you don't see disk errors, etc., it could be the internal issue around sync